# Почему исключения в асинхронном коде считаются необработанными?

Tags: c#, исключения, async-await

Есть код скачивания файлов, на нижнем уровне есть простой цикл с ограничением, чтобы сделать несколько попыток скачивания, выглядит упрощенно вот так:

```
private static bool Failed = false;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, a) => { throw a.Exception; };
  ChapterDownload().Wait();
}

public static async Task ChapterDownload()
{
  try
  {
    var pages = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);
    var pTasks = pages.Select(page =>
    {
      return PageDownload()
      .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", t.Status, t.IsFaulted));
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(pTasks.ToArray());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //
  }
}

public static async Task PageDownload()
{
  if (Failed)
    throw new Exception("boom");

  try
  {
    // var file = await new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(@"http://example.com"));
    var file = await DownloadFile(new Uri(@"http://example.com"));
    if (file != null)
      throw new Exception("Restart download, downloaded file is corrupted");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Failed = true;
    await PageDownload();
  }
}

public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadFile(Uri uri)
{
  byte[] result;
  WebResponse response;
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

  try
  {
    response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
      await response.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(memory);
      result = memory.ToArray();
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
  if (response.ContentLength == result.LongLength)
    return result;
  return null;
}
```

Проблема в чём - в текущем виде, происходит `UnobservedTaskException`, с текстовкой `boom`, т.е. явно моё. При этом, стоит мне заменить скачивание с самопала на `webclient` - `UnobservedTaskException` больше не возникает. В чём разница?

Comment: В Вашем коде Вы нигде не просматриваете исключение из `PageDownload()`, поэтому оно и считается необработанным.

Comment: @PetSerAl добавление `ContinueWith` фактически скрывает от меня падающую таску, что ли? Потому как `ChapterDownload` делает `await` всех тасок.

Comment: Именно так. Вы ждёте завершения только продолжения, а не исходной задачи.

Comment: @PetSerAl и что надо сделать в `ContinueWith`, чтобы исключение таски считалось обработанным?

Comment: Исключение надо просмотреть: `t.Exception`; или перевыбросить: `t.Result`, `t.Wait()` или `t.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @PetSerAl неочевидное какое то поведение, что надо на него посмотреть. Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: @PetSerAl оформите как ответ? Помогло, теперь всё как и ожидалось. Пришлось хотя бы логгировать исключение, чтобы не сыпалось как "необработанное".

Comment: На таску можно навесить несколько продолжений с помощью `ContinueWith` с разными значениями параметра `TaskContinuationOptions`: например `OnlyOnFaulted` для логгирования, `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` для нормального продолжения работы и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно и без параметров сделать то же самое. Или намекаете на то, что можно сделать заглушку для `OnlyOnFaulted`, которая будет логгировать и "скрывать" исключения?

Comment: Да, я имел в виду своего рода заглушку.

Comment: @PetSerAl оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы исключения задачи (`Task`) считались обработанными и не вызывали событие `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` необходимо их перевыбросить, например `t.Result`, `t.Wait()` или `t.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, или просмотреть, обратившись с свойству `Exception`: `t.Exception`.

В Вашем коде проблема возникает потому, что вы ждёте завершение не самих исходных задач, а их продолжений. В то время как продолжения не делают ничего, чтобы обработать исключения исходных задач. В результате исключения, возникшие в исходных задачах, остаются необработанными.